# Powershell Exchange Auto reply and MSRtcip

Tags: powershell, email, active-directory, exchange-server

I am trying to write a .ps1 to do the following

- Set email auto response for emails sent to me & to exclude certain addresses
- Clear AD msRTCSIP-Line information
- Remove the user from specific AD groups
- Move user to a specific AD OU
- Disable AD user

Append & Error handling would also be very useful

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to ask your question :) Are you stuck at a particular step? Please tell us which one, and let us know what you've already tried and how it failed

Comment: Hi Mathias, 

Apologies, I can set the OOO but  don't know how to exclude certain addresses. 
I can remove the user from groups, move to OU and disable.

I just wondered if someone could help piece it all together as opposed to me running multiple commands